# How to make Dictionary<int, int> by javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to make Dictionary by javascript. How to add key and value like this C# example

```
Dictionary<int, int> myDic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
x.Add(1, 4);
x.Add(2, 6);
```

when I use javascript Array() like this

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray['one'] = 1;
myArray['two'] = 2;
```

and send myArray to my action in asp.net mvc2 by ajax request I found the array with out keys like this ,3,5 and I want the keys also.

thanks

Comment: Can you give an example illustrating what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: [Hash Tables in Javascript](http://www.mojavelinux.com/articles/javascript_hashes.html)

Comment: thanks for ur help, but how to add multiple values to the same key

Answer (score 1):

You won't need to use jQuery for that: JavaScript can be used to make something like [Hash Tables](http://www.mojavelinux.com/articles/javascript_hashes.html).

I am not quite sure what you mean by "how to add multiple values to the same key". You can use an array as a value using this method, like

```
var myHash = new Hash('one', new Array("first", "second"), 'two', 2);
```